# What are Apache Camel beans?

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

I have very recently started working with Apache Camel. I have an OK grasp of components, endpoints, routes and processors and I have started learning some EIPs as well.

However, I can't seem to understand what are Camel Beans. At first I thought they were just POJOs, but apparently they are related to Camel's registry and I am confused:
http://camel.apache.org/bean.html

Could someone be kind enough to give me a "What are Camel Beans for dummies" definition?

Thanks in advance, Pedro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Camel Beans as just POJOs. However Camel "knows" their existence and it can invoke methods in that POJO. For camel to know this bean, you'd have to register this bean via spring/Jndi.